# I am very versatile

Tags: riddle, word

I can be in.
I can be on.
I can be out of, and about.
I can be half. And half again.
Or double in a rush.

I can stand still, and I can fly.
I can be bought. I can be shared.

What am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My answer is

> Time

I can be in.

> Being in time - as in musically in time with a beat

I can be on.

> Be on time - referring to being punctuality

I can be out of,

> Out of time - no time left

and about.

> About time - better late than never

I can be half.

> Half-time - as in the break in football

And half again.

> Possibly three-quarter time in music. (or quarters in telling the time)

Or double in a rush.

> Double time - referring to doing things quickly

I can stand still,

> Time can stand still when everything seems to stop.

and I can fly.

> Time files when you're having fun.

I can be bought.

> Buying time - referring to creating a diversion

I can be shared.

> Timeshare

Comment: Well done. That's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 8):

You are

> Time

I can be in.

> "in time"

I can be on.

> Right on time!

I can be out of, and about.

> You're out of time. It's about time.

I can be half. And half again.

> Half-time! Quarter time!

Or double in a rush.

> Double-time (, private!)

I can stand still, and I can fly.

> Time is standing still. Time flies when you're having fun.

I can be bought. I can be shared.

> This oughta buy me some time. Maybe I'll buy a timeshare.

What am I?

> You're time!

Comment: Not sure about "private". I think you were thinking about two-timing.

Comment: @Floris No, I was imploring a young soldier to move a little faster.

Comment: @question_asker So basically the command "Double Time, MARCH"

Answer (score 6):

My answer is a

> Bed

I can be in, I can be on

> Both refer to lying on top of a bed

I can be out of

> You get out of bed

and about

> About can mean near. Example usage: "The bird was fluttering about his bed"

I can be half

> A twin bed is half the size of a normal bed

And half again

> There used to be a such thing as a 3/4 size bed

Or double in a rush

> People sometimes call a full-size bed a double

I can stand still

> Beds normally do

and I can fly

> First-class cabins often have beds in them

I can be bought, I can be shared

> Beds can be bought, and you can share a bed

What am I?

> Yes, I know it's time, but I'll say a bed just because.

Comment: Nicely done. But not what I had in mind.

Comment: @Floris Thanks! When I first looked at the puzzle, this answer crossed my mind briefly for some reason, but I decided to take the idea and run with it.

Comment: Good answer, and I could be wrong but full and double are different sizes in the U.S.!

Comment: @Insane According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_size), they are the same.

Comment: @DanielM. So weird! Growing up I was under the impression they were different. That _is_ why I said I could be wrong :-)